# Intune error 80180014 enrolling Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows, entra-id, microsoft-intune

I'm trying to use Microsoft Intune for the first time. I have an A3 license which includes Intune and Entra ID/Azure Premium P1. I have Directory Sync running on one of our servers to sync our local AD with Azure AD and I also have Config Manager running on premises. I have configured the two CNAME records for `EnterpriseEnrollment.mydomain.com` and `EnterpriseRegistration.mydomain.com` as per Microsoft's documentation and confirmed that both are working.

I'm trying to enrol a 'Lenovo Thinkpad L14 Gen 1' laptop. I've just wiped the laptop and installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 Education 22H2 x64 so it's got no other software and is not domain joined etc. As the laptop was previously on the local domain, I've deleted it from Active Directory, Config Manager, entra.microsoft.com and made sure it wasn't listed at intune.microsoft.com. I want to enrol this as a corporate owned device for full control, not a personal device. To enrol the laptop I am logging on with my domain account during the OOBE setup.

My user account is licensed for Intune and Entra ID/Azure Premium P1 (I have also tried a different account with the same licenses). Conditional Access is configured on the domain to enforce MFA which is working fine during enrolment. I had proxy issues at first, so I'm now using an external network which has no proxy server (I.e. a standard home Internet connection).

For some reason I keep getting the following error (80180014):

[image: Windows OOBE enrolment error]

The link in the screenshot says the device is not supported, but according to Microsoft it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/supported-devices-browsers

I've also found the following link which says the error is due to device restrictions having 'Windows (MDM)' disabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/intune/device-enrollment/troubleshoot-windows-enrollment-errors. But as you can see in the screenshot below, it's only disabled for personal devices.

[image: Intune device restrictions]

**Other things I've tried**

Before trying to enrol via the OOBE, I tried enrolling via Settings > Accounts > Access work or school, via the web portal and the app from the Microsoft Store (I've wiped the laptop and can't remember the name of it). I started getting an error saying that personal devices are not supported (as I have them disabled) and read that using the OOBE would register the device as a corporate device. I also tried entering the laptop serial number in Intune under  `Devices > Enroll devices > Corporate device identifiers` but later read that this isn't supported for Windows devices (only tablets etc).